# One factor with two levels with random group effect

Tags: anova, random-effects-model, blocking

I'm testing the hypothesis: prey exposed to the chemical cues of a predator will have lower feeding rates than prey feeding without predator chemical cues.

In this simple food chain the top predator is a crab, which feeds on a snail, which feeds on mussels.

To test my hypothesis I will have a (+)crab treatment where snails forage on mussels in the presence of crab chemical cues, and a (-)crab treatment, where snails forage on mussels without crab chemical cues. Additionally, I will have a control treatment to measure the background mortality of mussels without snail predation. At the beginning of the experiment, all replicates will have the same number of mussels. At the end of the experiment, I will count how many mussels are still alive in order to determine snail feeding rates for each treatment.

Here is my issue: in order to have a sufficient amount of experimental replicates, I have to use two large tanks. So the design really looks like this:

| Tank | (+)crab | (-)crab | control |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n = 6 | n = 6 | n = 6 |
| 2 | n = 6 | n = 6 | n = 6 |

The replicates within each tank are not exchanging water with one another. The tanks are really just acting as a container that holds the replicates.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to analyze this data. Theoretically, there shouldn't be any differences in each respective treatment between tanks. For example, there should be no difference in the mean feeding rate of the (+)crab treatment between tanks 1 and 2. It's not really a blocked design because the replicates are not blocked by nuisance factors, the nuisance factors are the tanks themselves. What type of statistical analysis should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it correct in the title, this is a random effect that you should include in the model (versus the other fixed effects).
If you want all the dirty details, check out Gary Oehlert's free book, chapter 11 is about random effects:
[http://users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/Book.html](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Egary/Book.html)

If you're looking for how to physically code this, let us know what system (R?)
It's been a while since I did a random effects model in R, but I can dig through my notes if you need help on that.

Comment: Great thanks! Just wanted to make sure my thinking was correct. I will be using R when I eventually run the analysis.

Comment: I looked through my notes on this, I don't think I can describe it well so I'll leave you to google something like "random effects anova in R," you'll actually have a mixed model but I suspect you'll get better results looking for "random effect".

Comment: Okay thank you! I appreciate you taking the time